# How would I scale Java source code with graphics constants by creating a new file in which the old graphics constants are doubled?

Tags: java, graphics, java-io, filewriter

The purpose of this program is to take the graphics constants from a separate Java source code file and write an updated file with the graphics constants in that same Java program either scaled up or down.

However, I'm not sure how to only change numbers in certain lines and ignore others. For example, I don't want to change the numbers for the RGB values so the colors would remain the same.

So how would I exclude certain lines from changing the number values?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class ScaleUpOrDown {
    public static void main() {
        File myFile = new File("SampleGraphics2.java");
        try {
            Scanner filereader = new Scanner(myFile);

            do {
                BufferedWriter OutputF = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("OutputForDouble.txt", true));
                String line = filereader.nextLine();
                int nu = 0;
                String[] diffArray;

                String sp[] = line.split(" ");
                Pattern patternP = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
                for (int i = 0; i < sp.length; i++) {
                    Matcher matchN = patternP.matcher(sp[i]);
                    while (matchN.find()) {
                        sp[i] = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(matchN.group()) * 2);
                    }
                }
                Arrays.stream(sp).forEach(string -> extraFunction(string));
                OutputF.append("\n");
                OutputF.close();
            } while (filereader.hasNextLine());
            filereader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error, file not found!");
        }
    }

    public static void extraFunction(String Bigstring) {
        try {
            BufferedWriter writingT = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("OutputForDouble.txt", true));
            writingT.append(Bigstring + " ");
            writingT.close();
            System.out.print(Bigstring);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to write to file.");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please show what the input file looks like and what the output file *should* look like.

Comment: You're basically going to have to parse and interpret the Java code so you can determine which numbers to scale.  Unless you have 1,000 programs or more to scale, the task can be done much easier by hand.